# Run Time Environment

Tags: runtime, runtime-environment

I wanted to know what exactly is run time environment at system level(operating system). Is it somehow related to the resources required at run time or something else? I saw a similar question posted on a forum, explaining how it is used in java. I have no knowledge of Java, so very little I could derive from the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Runtime Environment` : i'll explain it as a platform which works as a trasporter or communication channel between your program and Operating System.

JRE is an example of that. `Java Runtime Environment`

It contains all the required libraries to run your `.jar` or `wrapped .jar (an .exe)` to run smothly on any system without having JDK (Java Development Kit) installed.

you can go through [here](http://www.javabeat.net/qna/67-wat-is-the-difference-between-jrejvm-and-jdk/) for starting understanding.

Comment: @Azodius, I think .jar is not an exe , its more of .zip archive, which contains the .class files.

Answer (score 1):

Look first at [wikipedia page on runtime environments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_environment)

For Java, it is usually the implementation of the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jvm) whose specification is [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/); it notably contains the [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), the [class loader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_loader) and the [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)